# EMA mean reversion Algo : Short Trade

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am very new to pine script and trying to generate an EMA mean reversion algo.
Conditions are as follows
**TimeFrame: 10mins,
Time 9:15 a.m to 10:15.a.m otherwise no entry**

- Candle low should be far away and above from the user input EMA (example 7EMA).
- If there are multiple candles far away from that EMA than consider that candle which has
  farthest low.(Ambiguity: havenot decided how much far way the low should be but it should not be
  very near to the EMA)
- If the low of that farthest candle is broken take short enrty,if time is > 10.15 no entry to be
  taken.
- SL should be the HH(Highest high) of the candles which are away from the EMA.

  As I am new to Pine Script
- I have only been able to plot EMA.
- Also found out the candles whose close and low are away from EMA.
- Yet to decide the exit condition

Code:

```
//@version=5
strategy("7ema", overlay=true)
ema_input=input.int(7,'EMA Length')
ema_=ta.ema(close,ema_input)

plot(ema_)
barcolor((close > ema_) and (low > ema_ or high < ema_) ? color.black : na)
```

[image: Candles detached from EMA]

Comment: I already added what I have tried @vitruvius also attached the image of the result I am getting. Now out of these black candles I am trying to find out which candle has the farthest low from the EMA.

Comment: @vitruvius let me post that code which I tried but was giving wrong{ resultstotalbars=(close > ema_) and (low > ema_ or high < ema_) 
plot(totalbars)}

Comment: @vitruvius other line of code which I tried  plot(ema_)
newLow=low+(ema_*0.015)
barcolor((newLow > ema_) and (newLow > ema_ or newLow < ema_) ? color.black : na)

Comment: @vitruvius I do agree that I should have posted the wrong codes I tried But what I have not understood about the comment 'Please ask one question' if I would be trying something then shouldn't I mention all the conditions

Answer (score 2):

You will have to first find when is the first time a candle is having low above ema. Then you have to check each successive candle above ema, if its low is above the previous low. If the low is below the previous low then you have to generate signal.
I have done a basic part of that without time checking etc. It will plot all such reversal like in this image

[image: Plot]

```
//@version=5
strategy("7ema", overlay=true)

ema_input=input.int(7,'EMA Length')
ema_=ta.ema(close,ema_input)

plot(ema_)

var pLowAboveEMA=0.0
var isClosingAboveEMA=false
var pHighBelowEMA=0.0
var isClosingBelowEMA=false
var buySignal=false
var sellSignal=false
var signalgeneratedafterbreach=false


if low>ema_
    if isClosingAboveEMA
        if low>pLowAboveEMA
            pLowAboveEMA:=low
        else if not signalgeneratedafterbreach
            sellSignal:=true
            signalgeneratedafterbreach:=true
    else
        isClosingAboveEMA:=true
        pLowAboveEMA:=low
        isClosingBelowEMA:=false
        signalgeneratedafterbreach:=false
if high<ema_
    if isClosingBelowEMA
        if high<pHighBelowEMA
            pHighBelowEMA:=high
        else if not signalgeneratedafterbreach
            buySignal:=true
            signalgeneratedafterbreach:=true
    else
        isClosingBelowEMA:=true
        pHighBelowEMA:=high
        isClosingAboveEMA:=false
        signalgeneratedafterbreach:=false
barcolor((close > ema_) and (low > ema_ or high < ema_) ? color.black : na)
plotshape(buySignal, "Long", shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, color = color.blue, size = size.small)
plotshape(sellSignal, "Short", shape.triangledown, location.abovebar, color = color.red, size = size.small)
buySignal:=false
sellSignal:=false
```

Comment: I was trying to edit code a bit also was trying to write it down in AFL. I tried to remove the buy condition and also when the low break it was considering the candle which is above EMA but what if the candle breaks the low but touches the EMA. You code helped a lot but I was able to do it in AFL. Posting it in another comment.

Comment: far = 1;
shortCondition = Ref(L,0)> EMA(C,5)*far AND TimeNum()>091500 AND TimeNum()< = 101500;
SL_price = ValueWhen(ShortCondi
ShortP= ValueWhen(ShortCondition,HHV(H,4);
Short = BarSince(ShortCondition)<=4 AND Ref(L,0)< ShortP AND TimeNum()<=100000;
Short = ExRem(Short, BarSince(Short)>3);
ShortPrice = ShortP;

pos=50;
SetPositionSize = (Pos,spsPercentOfEquity);

Comment: SL= abs(ShortP- SL_price);
n= Optimize("Profit Multiplier",2,1,5,0.25);
Cover = TimeNum()>=151500;
ApplyStop(0,2,SL,1);
ApplyStop(1,2,n*SL,1);

SetChartOptions(0, chartShowArrows | chartShowDates );
_N(Title = StrFormat("{{Name}}-{{INTERVAL}} {{DATE}} open %g, Hi %g, Lo %g, Close %g (%.1f%%) {{VALUES}}, O,H,L,C, Selectedvalue(ROC(C,1))));
Plot(C, "Close", ParamColor("Color", colorDefault), styleNoTitle| ParamStyle("Style")|GetPriceStyle());
Plot(EMA(C,5)),"ema",colorBlack);
PlotShapes(IIf(Short, shapeDownArrow, shapeNone),colorRed, 0,H, Offset = -45);

Comment: Now I have tradingview which supports Pinescript and Ambibroker is expensive.What if want to put a Stop Loss at the HH of the candle which is away from EMA, In AFl it was bit easier but free version doesnot support backtesting